# Convert any date format to en-US(mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss) Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

If I get any date format en-GB or European date format (mm.dd.yyyy) need to convert to en-US (mm/dd/yyyy) format.

Need to check a condition if it is not in en-US date format, then need to convert to en-Us format.

Comment: Mind to share with us your tried solution?

Comment: Did you try with Moment.js?

Comment: you can try date-fns library   https://date-fns.org/v1.30.1/docs/format

Comment: i cannot use any library. Need to write it in JavaScript. I tried to convert European date format.

Comment: I just noticed that you cite European format as "mm.dd.yyyy" - this is never used anywhere in Europe. All European countries primarily use DMY ordering (based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country)

Answer (score 0):

you can use intl dateformat

```
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0, 200));

// request a weekday along with a long date
var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', options).format(date));
// "December 20, 2012"
```

for more information https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat

**UPDATE**

as per OP comment

if your date is in your commented format you need to parse it first.

```
let parse = '29.9.2020 12:09:08'.split(/[.]|:| /);
let date = new Date(Date.UTC(parse[2], parse[1], parse[0], parse[3], parse[4], parse[5]));

var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', options).format(date));
```

after your parse date to valid format.. than you can reformat.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. but my date format is for eg: '29.9.2020 12:09:08'

Comment: @SruthyJoseph which date format the input or output

Comment: input date format is mm.dd.yyyy and output format should be mm/dd/yyyy.
input can be any format, but output should be mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: @SruthyJoseph I update my answer as per your commented date format

Answer (score 0):

**Important:** Are the non-US date formats guaranteed to use dots as delimiters? The standard in en-GB is to use slashes, so if you have a date `10/11/2020` it would be impossible to say if this is Nov 10th (en-GB) or Oct 11th (en-US).

---

If the non-US dates are *guaranteed* to be dot delimited, you can do something like this:

```js
const dates = [
    '11.10.2020 12:00:00',
    '10/11/2020 13:00:00',
]

const toNumbers = str => str
    .split(/\D+/)
    .map(Number)

const parse = dateStr => {
    let Y, M, D, h, m, s

    if (dateStr.includes('/')) {
        // is en-US
        [ M, D, Y, h, m, s ] = toNumbers(dateStr)
    } else {
        [ D, M, Y, h, m, s ] = toNumbers(dateStr)
    }

    // M - 1 because months are zero-indexed in the constructor
    return new Date(Y, M - 1, D, h, m, s)
}

// amend as needed
const options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric', hour12: false }

const fmt = date => {
    return date
        .toLocaleDateString('en-US', options)
}

console.log(dates.map(dateStr => fmt(parse(dateStr))))
```